# How to generate multiple RSA keys on one machine

Tags: go, rsa, ssh-keygen

Use case: a service that generates multiple(different) RSA Private/Public key pairs

Current code to generate a keypair:

```
reader := rand.Reader
bitSize := 2048

generatedKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(reader, bitSize)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

I'm using `crypto/rand`

However, it always generates the same pair. How does key generation work with something like rand.reader and what's the best approach to creating a different Private/Public key pair on the same machine?

Comment: Are you using `crypto/rand` or `math/rand`?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/pJNlR8Fo6kq this generates different key pairs every time.
I'm using your same code. May be you could mention what rand package you are using.

Comment: I'm using ```crypto/rand```.

Comment: What is your evidence that it always generates the same keypair? Did you properly output the generated keypairs and then compare them with a file comparison program like unix `cmp`, or did you just eyeball the result to reach your conclusion?